# Trying to stop repeats in matchup generator

Tags: python, sql

So I'm creating a matchup generator for my friends since 2k is launching soon, but I can't figure out how to stop the repeating of the names of my list when the matchups are generated. I've only been learning Python for a few days. I've tried `random.sample`, and `random.choice`(my original code, which I now realize is not right). The code works but it generates repeated values, i.e. 'red vs red', 'blue vs blue'. How do I stop this?

```
import random

print("Matchup Generator")
bracket_one = ["sub", "gc", "ron", "tame", "clak", "moe", "matic", "kapp"]
bracket_two = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green"]

lineup = int(input("Press '1' for bracket one or press '2' for bracket two: "))

if lineup == 1:
    print("You chose a bracket of 8 competitors. \n The matchups are: \n")
    x = range(4)
    #print(x)
    for x in x:
        matchups_one = random.sample(bracket_one, 1) + " vs " + random.sample(bracket_one, 1)
        print(matchups_one)
elif lineup == 2:
    print("You chose a bracket of 4 competitors. \n The matchups are: \n")
    y = range(2)
    #print(y)
    for y in y:
        matchups_two = matchups_two = random.choice(bracket_two) + " vs " + random.choice(bracket_two)
        print(matchups_two)
else:
    print("You did not press '1' or '2'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html, quote - **replace** -  Whether the sample is with or without replacement. Default is True, meaning that a value of a can be selected multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you're not removing the elements you randomly sample from the bracket. Therefore, you always have a chance of getting elements you already saw when you sample the bracket again.

Another note - while it doesn't really change the result, you can sample 2 competitors at each matchup, instead of sampling 1 competitor twice for each matchup.

Then for each matchup, you will randomly draw 2 competitors and remove them from the list. Then the next matchup will pick 2 new competitors from the remaining competitors in the list.

With a few other adjustments, the code might look something like this:

```
import random

print("Matchup Generator")
bracket_one = ["sub", "gc", "ron", "tame", "clak", "moe", "matic", "kapp"]
bracket_two = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green"]

lineup = int(input("Press '1' for bracket one or press '2' for bracket two: "))
if lineup != 1 and lineup != 2:
    print("You did not press '1' or '2'")
    quit()

bracket = bracket_one if lineup == 1 else bracket_two
num_competitors = len(bracket)
print(f"You chose a bracket of {num_competitors} competitors. \n The matchups are: \n")
num_matchups = num_competitors // 2
for i in range(num_matchups):
    competitor1, competitor2 = random.sample(bracket, 2)
    bracket.remove(competitor1)
    bracket.remove(competitor2)
    matchup = f"{competitor1} vs. {competitor2}"
    print(matchup)
```

Comment: Thank you.  And you're using syntax I haven't seen before.  Great learning tool.